# Need help improving my question to remove the Question Ban

Tags: support, post-ban

Here is the question that I think is preventing me from asking further questions:
[Do I need to use Firebase to Access All Hacker News Articles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69609360/do-i-need-to-use-firebase-to-access-all-hacker-news-articles)

I have a **Question Ban** was imposed on me about 5 days ago, and I'm considerably stuck on how to lift it. Here is what I've done so far:

1. I researched in the Help Center on improving my questions (clarifying the question, removing unnecessary clutter, made sure I wasn't asking multiple separate questions in one post, etc., and it did help! I got some points back.
2. I have made countless revisions and improvements to **all** of my questions.
3. I made sure to include clear code of what I did (as clear as I can make it.)
4. I made sure to respond properly to the responders who provided answers
5. I double checked the tags

What more can I do?

Comment: Do you have any deleted questions weighing you down? https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/current

Comment: OP's comment on their question: "This post is is making it very difficult in helping me understand why the question is poorly asked, and am thus having a lot of trouble lifting the question ban. I've been looking over the help center for question asking and it looks like I hit the major markers.... I tried to improve all my questions, checked formatting and spelling, tried to be as clear as I could. Can someone help? I have spent 2 days figuring out how to improve the questions and release the question ban. :("

Comment: nothing really. Be very patient is all you can do after you have exhausted your editing capabilities. It is not the editing that pulls you out of the hole, it is the fact that people cast new upvotes or remove existing downvotes. Settle with the idea that you're not going to be asking a new question for potentially a long while.

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/71012993) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/70748905) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/70719992) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/69860699) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/69548683)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt it's just that one question which has lead to a question ban. [Have a look at your deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/current)

In terms of formatting, your question looks okay. It could maybe be a little neater, and I fixed up your indentation for you. I can understand what you're asking pretty readily. It's on-topic, and has a code snippet which illustrates where you're at.

But at the heart of it, the question you're asking about isn't very good. The answer is already in your question

> Do I need to use Firebase to Access All Hacker News Articles?

Clearly no, you've got a code fragment which doesn't use Firebase and is accessing a Hacker News article.

From the [Hacker News API docs you link in your question](https://github.com/HackerNews/API) (emphasis mine):

> **If you can** use one of the many Firebase client libraries, **you really should**.

The docs provide information about the HTTP API endpoints, and how to use them. None of which is Firebase-specific.

Just stepping back and re-reading your question and the docs you link, you should have been able to find the answer to your question by yourself.

Comment: Wait, so the deleted questions are factored in as well? I didn't know that. Thank you very much for your advice on improving the Firebase. It will help in the future to prevent any future bans.

Comment: Yes ... of course they are.  Otherwise it would be easy for someone to bypass a question ban by simply deleting their bad questions.

Comment: @EmekaA - All activites are considered in a question or answer banned

Comment: @EmekaA I really hope you have read [the help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) mentioned when you got question banned: "*[Deleting your questions will not help.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)*"