# Can we please change the policy on banning people from asking questions?

Tags: feature-request, post-ban

Apparently my account is being blocked questions because there are questions that I've previously asked that have not been very popular, or have been down voted or deleted. As a result, I can only ask one new question every six months apparently, and if that question is not very popular then it will continue my question ban. This is odd for a site that is for helping developers answer their pressing technical questions. What you're basically saying is that if my problems are not common enough, then I cannot ask them. I think that is a very odd requirement. Can we please change the policy around question bans to make this site more useful?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn’t a personal help desk. It’s a repository of high-quality Q&A. “Helping” is a side-effect for the question author and is mainly targeted at future readers. The site is useful _because_ we have high quality standards. _“if my problems are not common enough, then I cannot ask them”_ — Where did you get this idea?

Comment: Where did I get that idea? Everytime I ask about this question ban, I'm told that not enough people upvoted my questions. Therefore I conclude that the issues I'm asking about are maybe not common enough, so therefore I am being penalised for even asking them. It's really a crazy catch-22 situation since I can't know how common an issue is until I ask it, and if I ask it and it's not common, then you guys remove my ability to ask further questions... something is wrong with the process.

Comment: _"Therefore I conclude that the issues I'm asking about are maybe not common enough, so therefore I am being penalised for even asking them"_. Another thing one could infer is that the posted questions were found either poor, or unsuitable for the site. Be open to consider this scenario as well.

Comment: You can find out whether an issue is common by searching for it. That's how we find duplicates.

Comment: @Anthony. Question bans occur because you have too many _negatively_ scoring questions. Lack of voters isn't the problem. The question _quality_, which results in downvotes, is the problem.

Comment: @Anthony. Voting on Meta is different. It's often used to expressed (dis)agreement with the question. That doesn't make the voters "a-holes". Note that meta votes down't affect your reputation.

Comment: "Can we please change the policy around question bans to make this site more useful?". The site is not made useful by being able to ask questions, asking questions is what you do when there are no other options. The site is useful and remains to be useful because it is filled with existing knowledge you can *find*. I have not had to ask a question yet, I could find everything.

Comment: Yes please.  As a start, users who ask questions that are dupes of Q on the first page of the tag FAQ sbould be question-banned for life.

Comment: Did you take [the first step](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416125/#comment895735_416125)? (The canonical is *[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers...”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/)* - with a lot of advice.) There are [also  alternative sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/409391). [A longer, but less credible list](https://www.quora.com/What-are-other-question-asking-websites-like-Quora).

Answer (score 13):

It would make the site less useful because it would get clogged up with poor quality questions and answerers would have a much harder time finding useful questions to answer.

What we're saying is that if your question is common it's most likely asked already and you should be looking it up rather than asking it yet again and forcing the rest of us to find the duplicate for you. If you don't understand the existing answers you can always ask a question to get them explained then you'd show your research by linking to those existing questions and answers you've already found.

The ban is also there to motivate you to fix your existing poor quality questions. If it doesn't then so be it.

Comment: I disagree. Providing more freedom to let people ask the questions to help them solve the issues they're having would improve the site. If I have an issue, most likely others are in the same boat and will benefit from me asking about it. If you mute me, then the site is less useful to everyone.

I'm not going to waste time going back and editing deleted questions I asked years ago sorry.

Comment: @Anthony You previously mentioned that you switched to SO from Quora. Why did you do so? Was it not because you found this site more useful than Quora?

Comment: @Anthony. no. That "freedom" will significantly affect the signal to noise ratio, with poor quality questions drowning out actual useful information, making it more and more difficult to find an answer to your question.

Comment: Yeah well thanks for your opinions. I've wasted enough of everyone's time. I only came to Meta to vent my frustration over StackOverflow's (in my opinion) draconian policies. I wish it would change, but with people like you obviously agreeing with the way it is run, I guess Quora is the site for me!

Comment: Sorry, this is not the place to vent. Have a good one over on Quora I guess