# Opinionated question for performance and readability improvements

Tags: discussion, questions

I have recently asked this question: [How to flatten a list of lists without using for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71428644/how-to-flatten-a-list-of-lists-without-using-for-loops), where I was looking for suggestions on how to improve the performance and readability of a snippet of Python code I had written.

I understand that the original question was opinionated, and I now know this is not the type of questions we are looking for on the forum, however I was wondering if there are ways I could improve the question (I have been banned from asking further questions on SO, and this is a community I really enjoy using, both asking and answering questions.)

Comment: This sounds more like a question for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: For discussion on performance questions: [What makes a "good" performance question on SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412875/2821954). Couldn't find a discussion for readability on MSO, except about the tagging issue.

Comment: I would recommend to rethink all constraints: Not using loops seems pretty arbitrary, is ill-defined (Is a comprehension a loop? Does the internal loop of `map` count?), and you even accepted an answer that uses a loop. Optimising performance is rather arbitrary when the use-case is not well-defined – what versions are you targeting, how large is the data, what is the common or worst case, ...? The readability part is dubious because that is pure opinion. Ideally, you wouldn't have any such constraints but merely ask a "How to flatten a nested, jagged list"?

Comment: That said, [there's a dupe for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists). So your chances of getting the question re-opened and upvoted are pretty slim; since it's still at a neutral score, leaving it be and focusing on more negatively received questions may be more productive.

Comment: Re *"I have been banned from asking further questions"*: [The first step](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416125/#comment895735_416125). (The canonical is *[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers...”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/)* - with a lot of advice.) You can also review [this list of alternative sites here on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/409391). [A longer, but less credible list](https://www.quora.com/What-are-other-question-asking-websites-like-Quora). [An older list on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13198/).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have updated the question again, removing the references to performance and readability (I understand the opinionated nature of those) and specifying a clear goal - not using explicit for loops, but using mapping and list comprehension.

Comment: “I now know this is not the type of questions we are looking for on the forum“ - It’s also not actually a forum. A question should have an answer it shouldn’t lead to a discussion or opinion about a topic. The good news is you will be given another opportunity to ask a well received question in 6 months

Comment: [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).