# Help me improve my mainly "OpenGL in Python" questions

Tags: support, post-ban, quality-improvement

I was banned from creating questions on Stack Overflow as my prior questions apparently weren't fitting. I would be very glad if someone could take a look at them and tell me what exactly I should edit or if someone is willing edit the question themself.

I tried improving the questions myself, but the questions weren't opened again, and the ban still stands.

Tips for the future would also be appreciated!

Comment: I think you have done a good job of improving them yourself.

Comment: Thank you @Dharman! Also thanks for additionally editing them again!

Comment: @Dharman, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75323213/my-texture-is-being-displayed-as-completely-black-in-pyopengl?noredirect=1#comment133345956_75323213) has been immediately been closed again, due to already being answered. (Even though some of the links have a different solution and a different effect to the output). Is there anything I can do? If this doesn't stop I will pretty much never be able to post on Stack Overflow again.

Comment: @AndreasSabelfeld: I will post an answer in a few minutes, but I believe all of the duplicates I added address the same problem: The default texture minification filter requires valid mipmaps. The solution is either to generate the mipmaps or to change the filter. Also note, that closing a question (afaik) doesn't contribute to a question ban. Votes are what is most relevant.

Comment: You can do a lot of searching before you post a new question. Asking questions should only be done once you thoroughly check that a similar one hasn't been asked before. If it still gets closed as a duplicate then at least you have a clear conscience that you checked and didn't found anything.

Comment: @BDL Okay, I just thought because one of them the issue was a white screen on the entire display and the accepted solution on the other post was using textures with dimensions of 2. But who am I to judge, I'm a complete beginner with OpenGL and Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Dharman As far as I remember I was already a few hours troubleshooting and haven't found an answer on Google. In the future I will directly search for the problems on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not exactly the best state of being for asking questions on Stack Overflow, to be honest. Stack Overflow comes with quality requirements that complete novices in a particular topic, especially something as heinously difficult as (3D) game programming, won't be able to likely achieve. There are sites dedicated to the topic of game development where you might find more of a safety net. Use the right tool for the job, Stack Overflow is definitely not for all your questions.

Comment: A [leading theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuCqeg4zV_o&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFJREVL6RmMnZP5U7sGYYi2&t=51s) is that deletion will only [make it worse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416125/#comment895735_416125).

Comment: Re (re)search success: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via MRE. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: For OpenGL specifically, in addition to @philipxy recommendation consider searching C/C++ answers/articles/book in addition to Python. For most of its [30+ years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenG), OpenGL was mainly C/C++ API and a lot of information is presented with those languages. According to BDL's comment Python version looks very similar to C/C++ one and concepts are the same between those bindings - so if you can't get Python-specific answer look for C one before posting (may need to learn basics of C - but that is not too hard - you need 30 years old version of C :) )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most of your question suffer from the same problem: They either include too much and irrelevant code, and/or they are missing important parts. I know that this is hard with OpenGL, since even a minimal program already contains several hundred lines of code.

I should probably add, that being very at the beginning of learning a new technology is probably not the best time to ask questions on Stack Overflow. SO has a very high bar for quality and a lot of research is being expected before asking, but it is hard to know the correct terms to search for when you are a beginner. Keep in mind that the main goal of Stack Overflow is to build a repository of high-quality questions and answers. Helping the asker is also important, but second to helping a lot of people. 1-1 mentoring is usually not going to work well here.

[**glGetUniformLocation() throws 'ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: TypeError: wrong type' [closed]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75338795/glgetuniformlocation-throws-ctypes-argumenterror-argument-1-typeerror-wron)

The question is based on a typo that wasn't obvious because the definition of `get_program_id` wasn't included. On the other hand a lot of other code irrelevant to the problem was posted (shader code never causes a python runtime error). I'm not sure if posting the question in a different way would have prevented the downvote, since it would still have been caused by a typo. But you would have prevent the back and forth in comments.

[**Why do objects in my window sometimes disappear and reappear?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334609/why-do-objects-in-my-window-sometimes-disappear-and-reappear)

There are two major problems here. First, the question asks about disappearing objects, but nothing in the question ever tries to draw an object. Only the screen get's cleared. Second, the question again contains not the right amount of code. There are a few snippets, but it's rather unclear how they are connected. You talk about your main loop, but the code of the main loop isn't included. Even after reading your answer, it is imho impossible to diagnose the problem, because the fix is in some code that isn't shown.

[**My texture is being displayed as completely black in pyOpenGL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75323213/my-texture-is-being-displayed-as-completely-black-in-pyopengl)

Again, parts of the relevant code is missing. Here, the shader is highly relevant, because there are different methods to access a texture, some of the require certain pre-conditions (like `texture(...)` requiring a valid mipmap pyramid), while others don't (like `texelFetch`).
The question also asks about a very common problem when working with textures and has tons of duplicates on SO and also offsite. I went ahead and added three duplicates.

Your self-answer probably received a downvote, because it is only half true. Yes, adding that code solves the problem. But the code doesn't have to be placed before `glTexImage2D`. It just has to be set before using the texture in a shader. In general, an answer should also try to include an explanation on why you have to do something besides showing what to do (see comment on the answer).

*Disclaimer: Since some of the question were posted in my area of expertise, I've interacted with some of them before the question here was posted*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I also noticed it is very hard for me to ask questions about OpenGL even though I am not good at it. So in the time I was banned I needed to come up with my own solutions. I don't think anybody could have helped me there as to how specific the problem was. In the future I won't ask questions like this anymore, except I am 100% were the problem lies and what causes it.

Comment: @AndreasSabelfeld: You don't need to know exactly where the problem is (or what it is), but with more experience it will be easier to identify which parts of your code are relevant and which aren't. I fully understand how hard how hard it is to learn OpenGL since it's a really unforgiving API (with little to no way to find out what went wrong), but keep at it, it get's better with time :)

Comment: @BDL is Python actually a  good learning ground for OpenGL? I honestly don't know - 25 years ago OpenGL was just pure C/C++ APIs and crazily hard then... I don't know if Python now have big enough OpenGL community to help a beginner - would learning at least basics of C/C++ and including those language to searches help or hinder OP from your point of view? - it may be good additional recommendation in the answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: My gut feeling is that the programming language shouldn't matter that much. I haven't used the Python API myself, but from what I saw in questions here on SO, it's almost identical to the C++ API (- the pointer handling).

Comment: A few Typos if you care...: "*Most of your question[+s] suffer*" + "*would have prevent[+ed] the back and forth*" + "*Only the screen get[-']s cleared.*" + "*Again, parts of the relevant code [is=>are] missing.*" + "*some of the[+m] require*" + "*Since some of the question[+s] were posted*" + "*before the question here was posted[+.]*"

Comment: @chivracq: Go ahead and edit them :)

Comment: Nope, I don't do Edits (1d and 50x trying before finding a "spot" in the "The Edit Queue is full, try again later..." + 2d for Approval), + I can't anyway on 'Meta'... (0.6k-Rep < 2k-Rep)