# Why was I question-banned again after self-deleting my closed question?

Tags: discussion, support, help-improvement

I have already asked here yesterday for help to improve my posts and I'm very grateful for that.

I was banned from posting questions on Stack Overflow and you helped me to revert that.

Yesterday I posted a question again about programming a terminal user interface for macOS in Python that wasn't asked before, I made sure of that.
Stack Overflow warned me that posting a question could result in a new ban if it isn't well received. But I thought what use does Stack Overflow provide me if I fear to ask questions, so I posted it anyway.

Nobody could give me an answer, and the next morning (in my time zone) it was closed because the question was apparently already answered. I checked the link and that was the exact post I already had seen when researching for answers. I even copied some bits of the code from there.
But that didn't even answer my question the slightest. What I wanted is something additional to what I already have, which isn't in that post.

But as it was just a minor detail and the user interface was good enough I thought I'd leave it be and just delete the question to not risk a downvote and be banned again.

Look at that, I can't post again!

Personally I think it's a flaw in Stack Overflow's design. It shouldn't be this frustrating for new users to ask questions. I get that a certain degree of quality should be maintained on the site, but if the question was never asked before, even a negative rated post could provide help in the future to somebody researching the topic. The level of knowledge from the asker shouldn't affect the rating of the question (unless it fundamentally is a reason for the issue) as the person is here *exactly because he doesn't understand* something.

Anyway, I don't know how I could revert that ban as all my other questions have been improved and I deleted the newest question out of fear, now unable to edit it. (I know I could post again in six months, but that isn't worth the hassle.)

This probably is my last post then, except if some of you have an idea.

Comment: I mean, if the duplicate doesn't work, *ideally* the solution there is to edit your question to clearly indicate how your situation is different such that the duplicate is obviously not relevant. But i generally agree that the question ban is a bit too tough against users who clean up their own content that wasn't up to par.

Comment: I know, but the question was rather a small detail than a big problem, that's why I didn't want to risk anything. But in the end it didn't matter I guess,

Comment: The problem probably isn't that it has 0 votes, but that you deleted it. Deleted questions count against the ban. I suggest you undelete it and edit it to explain why it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Deleted questions count against you, especially if they have answers. Write up a revision before undeleting so you can make the edit immediately after.  Explain how the question doesn't answer yours. (And make sure you've properly cited any code that you took.)

Comment: I don't see any questions psoted by you yesterday on [so]; *deleted* questions (with a score <=0) contribute much more strongly to a question ban, than say a 0 score undeleted question with an answer. If you simply deleted the question because it was closed that was the wrong solution; edit the question to address the closure reason. If that reason is it's a duplicate, then *explain* in your question why the duplicate doesn't answer the problem you have.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I didn't even know that you could undelete questions. I will do that now and hope for the best.

Comment: I would add that if there's something that differentiates your question from the previous dup, be sure to acknowledge the dup and explain why they're different. (perhaps you did this already) 
Thank you for taking the time to improve things!

Comment: @code11 just did that. You can see it for yourself and tell me ig you think it is clear enough.

Comment: "and the next morning (in my time zone) it was removed because the question was apparently already answered. " - please note that you ... *misinforming* people with that statement - *you* personally deleted the post (which everyone now can see from https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75584935/timeline). I'd strongly recommend to fix that problem with this post (and in the future use correct terms - here and on main site - closed as duplicate != deleted... and indeed what you were *expected* to do was linked from the duplicate closure message... but you are not alone not seeing that)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "[...] I thought I'd leave it be and just delete the question to not risk a downvote and be banned again." I mentioned very clearly that i've deleted the question myself afterwards and also stated it in the comments. First the question got removed then I deleted it. I even explained it in the right order.

Comment: "First the question got removed then I deleted it"???? What do you mean "removed"? If some question was *deleted* you can't delete is second time... If question was *closed* than it is in no way removed from anywhere. Please check the help topics to see what states a post can be in and use the right/expected terms to describe the state instead of coming up with your own.

Comment: Excuse me what I meant was 'closed'

Comment: What exactly do you wish to discuss? What the title states? Closure of your question? How the ban still affects you?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that the ban system of Stack Overflow is flawed and too frustrating to new users. But I think this is something that is long known to SO users from what I've heard.

Comment: The ban system is the key to the success of Stack Overflow. Or do you really think high quality content appears here "organically"? If you believe that to be true then why are forums like Quora and reddit and the infamous Yahoo! Answers not as good, if not better when it comes to quality of content?

Comment: Asking good questions is *hard*, @AndreasSabelfeld ; the site doesn't hide that. The problem, from the perspective of a lot of users who take the time to answer questions, is that a lot of questions don't take the time to ask good questions; they frequently lack research, or are unclear/unhelpful. The bigger the site gets, the more questions that have already been asked exist, and so asking a *new* good question that not gets harder as time passes.

Comment: Purely from an English standpoint, I'd consider posts with 0 score to be "not well received." A positive score indicates a positive reception. A non-positive score indicates a non-positive reception; "not well-received."

Comment: I tried looking up the question you're talking about. "With this exact code the program halts everytime when sys.stdin.read(1) gets called and waits until any input is being made. I don't want that. I want my program to continue running if there was no significant input." **What does this mean**? What input is "significant"? When you say "was", what time interval are you referring to?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Any input except no input. So anything but an empty string ('').

Comment: *"now unable to edit it"* this can't be true; unless the post is locked (which it isn't) you will be able to edit your undeleted question.

Comment: @Larnu that was unknown to me previous to this question. I apologize. There are many flaws with this post but I think deleting this would be very counter intuitive in this situation.

Comment: I managed to understand what you want with the question. I edited for clarity, upvoted it, and fixed the duplicate link to something that I am fairly confident is what you actually want.

Comment: Thank you @KarlKnechtel you worded it better than me. I will try the solution you provided later.

Comment: see also: [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601) _"Whether a post was deleted is mostly irrelevant to the question ban. If someone tells you otherwise, tell them they're wrong; if you see a meta post that says otherwise, edit it. What matters are poorly-received posts. That is, questions that are downvoted, closed, or flagged as inappropriate in some way... The one exception involves deleting a question right after someone posts an answer to it..."_

Comment: "I thought I'd leave it be and just delete the question ..." - Asking a question, then deleting it because it has received downvotes, is exactly what you shouldn't be doing.  **I would even going beyond that statement, asking a question, and then deleting it should be avoided at all costs.** You say that the duplicate, did not answer your question, but did you indicate that in your question?  Did you go beyond simply saying, "I know a question already exists but it doesn't answer my question", and go into specific detail on why it didn't answer your question?

Comment: Likely related: *[Help me improve my mainly "OpenGL in Python" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423403/)*

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunate with collateral damage. The design reason is probably to prevent abuse by users who are *only* interested in extracting value from the unpaid volunteers. They would delete the question ***the very moment*** they got a satisfactory answer to hide it from the instructor/teacher. For example, self-posted or [paid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417632/request-to-let-banned-users-ask-one-question-every-week#comment906279_417632) (through an intermediary) homework. They took advantage of ***the*** killer feature of Stack Overflow: very, very quick answers

Comment: It seems [they have now changed to ChatGPT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16612111/dong-li) instead. Or it could just be trolling.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't understand how your last comment is relevant to this thread.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question was closed as a duplicate *and* you deleted it. What do you think the system should view that as? A good question or a bad one?

If you think your question was incorrectly closed as a duplicate, the correct action is to edit your question to clarify how it is not a duplicate. This edit by you will *automatically* put the question in a review queue for other users to review it and determine whether it should be reopened.

If you delete the question instead, no one will see it, and you forfeit your chance to have it reopened. You're essentially 'admitting defeat'.