# How much setting bounties are effective to get out of question ban?

Tags: support, bounty, post-ban

Setting Bounties drop attention to your questions. So if I set a bounty on one of my well-written unanswered questions, will that be effective to get rid of my question ban?

Comment: If it gets you upvotes on that question, it might. If not then no. So it's your call whether you think it worth trying. The question ban algorithm is not public so nobody can give you a definitive answer, nor could we know how many upvotes your bountied question would get.

Comment: Your existing question record looks pretty poor, honestly. Am I right in assuming that you built up 131 reputation mostly with approved edits? If so, thank you for your contributions - we need more of that.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel more of what?

Comment: More editing work.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, but I'll find no reason to keep doing this if this ban exists.

Comment: The canonical is *[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers...”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/)*. Though it doesn't cover this aspect. What is the status on the [deleted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416125/#comment895735_416125) front? [Direct URL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/current).

Comment: One closed, one duplicate question. I think it's not easy at all for me to get out of this ban :-|

Comment: Will undeleting them help?

Comment: deleted questions cannot receive upvotes so they will always be a dead weight. Improve and undelete them so they can receive upvotes.

Comment: Before you ask questions you should do better research of a problem. And even if you ask question you have to pay more attention to comments and potential duplicates because they can hold solutions to your problem. Bounties on poorly researched questions can have negative effects.

Comment: @Matin - The only sure way to raise beyond the threshold of a question ban, is to use the single question your able to use, and repeat that process until the rate limit is no longer required. I would be shocked if you were question banned after only 2 poor deleted questions. Since you only have enough reputation for a single bounty, you should probably be told, you will lose that reputation regardless if you receive an answer or don’t receive an answer. There is no guarantee anyone will upvote your question. You want to avoid having a ton of questions that receive 0 votes.

Comment: On avg, putting bounties on questions attracts upvotes due to the kind of answerers who commonly browse bountied questions. There's certainly no guarantee that putting bounties on your questions would follow the average, at minimum the questions would need to be answerable by those answerers for them to put any effort into your question.

Comment: @Matin go through your questions that are -1 or so and edit them, same with answers, improve them and hopefully people will appreciate the quality of them. For your ones that are -6, -7, there is no point attracting attention to them as people will herd mentality them down further

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not by itself, no.

Attention to some of your unanswered questions may be a double-edged sword.  Because you've got a bounty attached to your question, mere mortals can't do the basic moderation tasks against it (like closure), so if the question is something the community thinks should be closed, it'll be flagged for moderator intervention.

That's also not to say that we couldn't just downvote the question if we think it's unclear.  Bounties don't keep your questions immune from that.

So in summary - attention *can* be good, but you can only realize the advantages of it if the *question* is also good.